# Why is array'First always 1 in this example?

Tags: ada

I have a array of Nodes:

```
  type NodeArray is array (Positive range 1 .. 5) of XNode;
```

The node has some data and an integer ID but thats not important right now.

The way I undestand it is that `array'First` (excuse the abuse of notation) always points or references the first item in a range or array, not the integer of the range type.

My question is why I always get 1 instead of the first entry in my array.

If you need to see more code I can provide it, I just thought I'd keep my example simple and short.

Comment: `myNodeArray'first` is an index. `myNodeArray(myNodeArray'first)` is an XNode. As to why the first index is 1, that's what you declared it to be.

Comment: so unless I modify the range (is that even possible ?) first will always be 1 because its the first index ?

Comment: It's your type declaration. Make it  0 or 101 ... or False or Tuesday if you like (those being enumeration values)

Comment: "The way I undestand it is that array'First (excuse the abuse of notation) always points or references the first item in a range or array, not the integer of the range type." Where did you get this incorrect idea from?

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter that was just my intuition coming from other languages like python or haskell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your

```ada
type NodeArray is array (Positive range 1 .. 5) of XNode;
```

defines a constrained array type ([ALRM 3.6(5)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-6.html#p5)), whose first index will always be 1.

If you want to use one type to create array objects with different index ranges, you need an unconstrained array type ([ALRM 3.6(3)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-6.html#p3)) with bounds like `Positive range <>` (note 1, once you’ve created such an object, its bounds are fixed; note 2, instead of `Positive` you can use any scalar appropriate to the problem).

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Zython is

   type Unconstrained_Node_Array is array (Positive range <>) of Float;

   subtype Constrained_Node_Array is Unconstrained_Node_Array (1 .. 5);

   U : Unconstrained_Node_Array (42 .. 44); -- must include the index range

   C : Constrained_Node_Array;              -- the index range is 1 .. 5

begin
   for J in U'Range loop
      U (J) := Float (J) * 2.0;
   end loop;

   Put_Line ("U'First: "
               & Positive'Image (U'First)
               & ", U (U'First): "
               & Float'Image (U (U'First)));

   for J in C'Range loop
      C (J) := Float (J) * 2.0;
   end loop;

   Put_Line ("C'First: "
               & Positive'Image (C'First)
               & ", C (C'First): "
               & Float'Image (C (C'First)));
end Zython;
```